# Como solucionar: keytool error Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: android, android-studio, sha1

Al tratar de conocer la huella digital Sha-1 del keystore de mi proyecto android estudio, para producción, me está mostrando este error, el alias y las contraseñas son correctas:

[image: Imagen que muestra el error al tratar de conseguir Sha-1]

Lo estoy haciendo en la consola desde la ubicación:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin
```

y ejecutando el comando:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -keystore C:\keystore\certificado.jks
    -alias aliasEjemplo -storepass Password-1 -keypass Password-2
```

Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Hey Ivan ¿Recuerdas tus password para el Keystore y para el alias?, en este caso te pide primero el del keystore pero estas asignando uno incorrecto :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recuerda que el password de tu Keystore y de tu alias pueden no ser los mismos, esto se define cuando creas el Kesytore de acuerdo al path del keystore que cargas supongo que es tu Keystore de producción.

Si escribes el mismo o este es incorrecto obtienes el mensaje:

> Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to read key ...
>   from store "C:...\myown.keystore": **Keystore was tampered with, or
>   password was incorrect**  at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$10(OutputScope.java:241)

Es importante guardar esta información, aunque el password puede ser el mismo, también se puede definir uno diferente, pero si no se escriben los datos correctamente, se produce el error mencionado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si, la contraseña es la misma para ambos y el alias también lo tengo claro, y lo confirmo al generar un APK, cuando genero un APK firmado con las contraseñas y alias que tengo lo genera sin problema.

Comment: Y las dos contraseñas son iguales.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, he intentado con otros keystore de otros proyectos y tambien me muestra el mismo mensaje, voy agregar un comentario mas de como lo escribo en la consola, porfa me confirmas si lo estoy haciendo bien, para el ejemplo uso datos de ejemplo.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin>  keytool -exportcert -list -v -keystore C:\Users\ivan.lobelo\AndroidStudioProjects\MapadeTintal\certificado_mapa_tintal.jks
    -alias Key0 -storepass 123456789 -keypass 26829710

Comment: me ha arrojado sha-1 con este comando keytool -list -keystore C:\Users\ivan.lobelo\AndroidStudioProjects\UniagustApp\uniagustapp_certificado.jks

Comment: @IvanAlfredo ahhh también puedes usar este, ya sea con el keystore o con el nuevo certificado .jks : https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: Yo imaginaba que keystore y el certificado .jks eran se referían a lo mismo; ahora estoy tratando de actualizar la app en playstore y dice que la firma no corresponde y el archivo .jks es el mismo que había usado antes, no se si despues de intentar conocer el sha-1 ocurrió algo.

Comment: keystore y el certificado .jks pueden ser el mismo pero debes crear el .jks a partir del keystore que usaste para firmar tu aplicación para producción https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfen/index.html , si creaste un .jks nuevo entonces este tendrá un SHA-1 diferente!